# c# aws lambda dll reference issues

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to publish an image resizing aws lambda function (written in c# for .net core v1.0) from vs2017.  I have tried several third party libraries compatible with .net core (Magick.net and SkiaSharp).  However, when executing the function, I am running into System.DllNotFoundException, saying the DLL for the library cannot be found.  At first, I thought my issues were specific to the library being used, but I get this error regardless of library used.

Any thoughts?  Maybe there is something special I need to do in visual studio to get the dll to upload to amazon?

Example error:  System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libSkiaSharp': The specified module could not be found.

If I can't use a third party image resizing library for c# aws lambda functions, then are there .net core resizing functions available (since system.drawing is only avail on windows, and aws runs on linux)

I get the error on first instance of using a function in the referenced DLLs.  Example for SkiaSharp:

```
using SkiaSharp;

using (var objectResponse = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name, s3Event.Object.Key))
{
   // THROWS THE DLL FOUND FOUND EXCEPTION
   using (var original = SKBitmap.Decode(objectResponse.ResponseStream))  
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code please

Comment: var original = SKBitmap.Decode(objectResponse.ResponseStream))  // THROWS THE DLL FOUND FOUND EXCEPTION

Comment: Thanks Ash, but please Edit your question and add the code there for all to see clearly

Comment: There are many ways to go wrong accessing a DLL...Once you phrase your question with code (and your Import statements if applicable) - the answers will come

Comment: thanks, I edited the question with a snippet of my code.

Comment: Did you use NuGet within Visual Studio to add the Skiasharp reference libraries?

Comment: yes I did use Nuget.

Comment: Does it work on your local machine?  If YES, then you need to publish a number of DLLs to Amazon...  Usually not just one DLL, but a whole set of DLL dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved the issue myself.  Instead of referencing the SkiaSharp library directly, I'm now referencing a linux wrapper for it (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Avalonia.Skia.Linux.Natives)   Now the dll is bundled with the deployment package

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick. For everyone, this is how you get SkiaSharp to work in AWS Lambda. As he says, instead of installing the `SkiaSharp` NuGet package, install the `Avalonia.Skia.Linux.Natives` NuGet package. That includes everything you need to use SkiaSharp within AWS Lambda.